# How to make Angular run tests for only those files that have been modified?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Basically, I would want `ng test` in watch mode to run corresponding tests for only those files that I modify and save.

I wouldn't want to use `fdescribe` or `fit` because this process is very manual and laborious and I'd have to change it back to `describe` and `it` after I'm done (to be noted, it still bloats the terminal with skipped statuses for all the skipped tests).

I am looking for something that I can pass as an argument to `ng test` which can then smartly detect file changes and run only their tests.

Comment: Only solutions I've found are here (they discuss linting, but I imagine the same could apply to testing): https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7612

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for that:

Angular version: **8.2.0**
Angular CLI version: **8.3.14**

1. You can run the test for only those files that you modify in your branch with the command

> ng test --only-changed

2. You can watch the files and run the test when you save

> ng test --only-changed --watch=true

Comment: --Only-changed does not exist in angular cli, please provide reference to angular source and documentation providing this feature